# Association between point distribution and a continuous variable using R

Tags: r, interpolation, spatial, analysis, nearest-neighbor

I have a data set consisting of the location of trees and measurements of soil C (SOC). All points (trees and SOC) have `x(0,50), y(0,50)` coordinates. First, I would like to check to see if the proximity of trees (points) influences the amount of SOC (continuous variable). Second, I’d like to do the same analysis using only a subset of the trees (say, only trees with a diameter of  >20 cm (dbh)). Can this be done in R using package 'spatstat' or 'ads'? I’ve looked around, but haven’t been able to find any solution to this problem yet. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Example from (Simon et al. 2013): http://postimg.org/image/goks26xr5/

Data:

```
library(spatstat)

soc<-data.frame(x=c(0,5,5,5,5,5,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,15,15,15,15,15.1,15.9,15,15,15,20,20,20,20,21,20,20,20,25,25,25,25,23,25,25,25,25,30,30,31.5,30,33,30,30,30,30,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,45,45,45,45,45,50), 
                y=c(25,35,30,25,20,15,40,35.2,30,25,20,15,10,45,40,35,30,25,20,15,10,5,45,40,35,30,25,20,15,10,5,50,45,40,35,30,25,20,15,10,5,0,45,40,35,30,25,20,15,10,5,40,35,30,25,20,15.5,40,35,30,25,20,15,10,35,30,25,20,15,25),  
                zsoc=c(2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,2,3,4,5,3,5,6,3,4,5,3,4,5,6,8,3,4,1,3,2,5,3,2,4,6,2,4,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,8,1.5,2,3,4,2.3,4,5,3,4,5,6,7,8,2,1,1,1,1,1,2))

tree<-data.frame(x=c(24,18,11,9,7,6,11,11,15,13,15,22,27,29,22,20,27,28,36,34,33,32,33,42,47,47,46,46,46,43,41,35,36,37,35,35,35,34,34,33,34,34,34,33,31,29,30,29,29),   
                 y=c(28.8,31.2,32.0,24.0,18.4,17.6,13.1,11.9,11.1,5.8,3.6,1.5,8.3,13.3,15.7,17.3,19.0,19.1,14.4,10.8,6.1,4.9,2.7,2.7,11.3,11.8,12.3,10.1,19.9,24.4,23.0,25.6,31.0,34.6,36.5,36.9,36.8,38.4,35.6,37.0,39.6,39.5,41.6,41.8,39.7,41.1,35.9,35.8, 35.0),    
                 zdbh=c(15,49,53,53,43,32,34,46,50,32,56,32,48,42,53,52,34,47,39,48,38,36,17,33,25,21,10,11,50,36,47,50,47,12,7,8,6,6,9,16,23,8,8,21,6,10,6,21,11))

soc <- ppp(soc[,1], soc[,2], c(0,50), c(0,50), marks=soc[3], unitname=c("meter"))

tree <- ppp(tree[,1], tree[,2], c(0,50), c(0,50), marks=tree[3], unitname=c("meter"))
```

Hope this works!

Example reference: Simón, N., Montes, F., Díaz-Pinés, E., Benavides, R., Roig, S., Rubio, A., 2013. Spatial distribution of the soil organic carbon pool in a Holm oak dehesa in Spain. Plant and Soil 366(1-2), 537-549.